# Не могу опубликовать контейнер на AWS ECS

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, amazon, amazon-web-services

Я пытаюсь опубликовать `docker-контейнер` на сервисе `AWS ECS` c помощью AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и после нажатия на Next появляется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю сейчас идет попытка создания кластера в который будет помещен контейнер и не получается определить `VPC` в котором необходимо поместить сам кластер.

Проверил и у меня во вкладке *Your VPCs* отображается одна запись,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*т.е. вроде что-то есть*.

Я также спокойно создаю EC2 инстансы и все работает без проблем.

Я не обладаю глубокими знаниями по администрированию AWS, но думаю если будут какие-то советы/предложения как исправить ошибку **"Failed to determine VPC for cluster: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"**, то сориентируюсь.

Comment: Любопытно. Только лямбды публиковал с помощью AWS Toolkit, о такой возможности для сервисов даже не задумывался. У нас всё скриптами делается. Поизучал.

Comment: У меня на вкладке Launch Configuration в поле VPC Subnets перечислены несколько штук. Правда, комбобокс неактивен, изменить в нём ничего нельзя. И поле Security Groups заполнено (изменить тоже нельзя).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, у меня тоже если смотреть прямо из AWS Explorer, то во вкладке `Amazon VPC > VPCs` в окне присутствует запись с VPC ID = vpc-f3ee1095, а по адресу `Amazon VPC > Subnets` отображаются три записи у которых значение поля VPC равно vpc-f3ee1095.

Comment: Думал также может какая-то роль не хватает, но ошибка гласит что что-то не может найти.